# Angular access form control by name from form group

Tags: angular

I have a page where I'm able to do `console.log(this.formGroup.controls)` and access all the controls on the page.  However, when I do `console.log(this.formGroup.controls['ctrlName'])` I get a null value.  I also tried to cast the control as a `FormControl` like so: `console.log(this.formGroup.controls['ctrlName']) as FormControl` but still I get null.

How, can I access the individual controls to programatically add validation?

Comment: could you add all the code with building formGroup ?

Answer (score 2):

As per Angular docs - since FormGroup inherits after AbstractControl you can use the [get method](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#get) to retrieve control by it's path, e.g.

```
this.formGroup.get('ctrlName')
```

Comment: I tried that already as well but same result.

Comment: Well, that implies that you provide wrong control name or path. Please, provide a stackblitz reproduction where this method does NOT work and we'll work from there.

Comment: `ctrlName` is a variable or a literal? if is a literal you should access as TotallyNewb say (always you use after create the formGroup)